# How to safely delete a list entity using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm building a todo list in CodeIgniter.

I get all the lists created by the current logged in user this way.

```
<?php
        $this->db->from('lists');
        $current_user =  $this->session->userdata('email');
        $st="list_by='".$current_user."'";
        $this->db->where($st, NULL, FALSE);
        $q = $this->db->get();

        foreach ($q->result() as $key => $row) {
            echo "<li>" . $row->listTitle;
        }
?>
```

Below I have this delete button:

```
<a class="delete_button" onclick="return confirm('Delete list?');" href="<?php echo site_url('lists/list_delete');?>" ><i class="icon-cancel"></i></a>
```

My question is, how to allow the user to delete only the lists created by him if I add `id="<? $row->id;?>`, I can inspect the code in browser and change the id to another value and delete a list from someone else.

What is the best method to secure that?

Comment: The only way is to check __on server__ that current user is the owner of the list.

Comment: @u_mulder Okay thank you :) one more question, how do I get the value of the id from the button and move it over to controllers/lists into the function list_delete which currently is this one 

   ` public function list_delete(){
        $this->db->delete('lists', array('id' => '1'));
        redirect('lists');
    }`

Comment: I'm not very familiar with codeigniter but you can either build your url like `/lists/list_delete/ID` where `ID` is an id of a list. Or create a form and process `submit` event with passing id as a form field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't stop users from manipulating client-side forms. You need to do the verification on the server-side. For example, in your `Lists` controller.

First, let's add the ID of the list to the URL, so the link would be:

```
<a class="delete_button" onclick="return confirm('Delete list?');" href="<?php echo site_url("lists/list_delete/{$row->id}");?>" ><i class="icon-cancel"></i></a>
```

In the controller:

```
class Lists extends CI_Controller {

    public function list_delete($list_id) {
        // 1. Check if the list found by $list_id belongs to the logged-in user
        // 2. If it is, delete the list
        // 3. If it's not, throw an exception, or redirect back with an error
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, would it be more secured if I use the list csrf hash rather than id?

Comment: No, not at all. **If implemented correctly**, `GET` requests are as secure as `POST` requests with CSRF protection. Just make sure to do the verification correctly.

Comment: I removed the CSRF link, as the answer is about GET requests.

Comment: thank you :) based on your information this is what I built (it works, but is it ok?) 
`public function list_delete($id){
        $this->db->from('lists');
        $current_id =  $id;
        $current_user = $this->session->userdata('email');
        $st="id='".$current_id."'";
        $this->db->where($st, NULL, FALSE);
        $q = $this->db->get();
        foreach ($q->result() as $key => $row) {
            if ($row->list_by == $current_user) {
                $this->db->delete('lists', array('id' => $id));
           } else {redirect('main/restricted');} .....`

Comment: There's a lot about this code that can be improved. But in the scope of your question, the most important thing you need to consider, is sanitizing the input (namely `$id`) before putting it into a database query. Never trust user's input. See what assets CodeIgniter provides for this purpose. As far as I remember, CodeIgniter only allows a predefined set of characters in URL segments, so you might be already safe. But anyway, make sure it's sanitized.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the user_id stored in session against the user_id from your list, also it is a good practice to use CSRF protection, you can create a encripted key with the user_id and other value from session, and send that encripted value in each request to the server, then in the server you decript the key and check if the data in that key correspond to the data of the user in session.

Or you can activate CSRF protection in Codeigniter:

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/security.html

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way to check if user can delete a list - is to **check on server** if current user is the owner of a list with such id.

About methods of passing list id to a server:

- the simpliest method is to create delete url something like `/lists/list_delete/ID` where ID is id of a list (e.g. `/lists/list_delete/21`)
  Bad thing about this approach is that if you use simple `$_GET` request - it's very easy for a bad guy to create a delete url.
- That's why we need to go deeper and use `$_POST` requests only for such kind of requests. Using this approach you can create a small form for each list and process a POST request on server:

  ```
  <form action="/lists/list_delete">
      <input type="hidden" name="list_id" value="LIST ID HERE" />
      <input type="submit" name="delete" value="DElete this list" />
  </form>
  ```

  Even in this case you should try to avoid CSRF and use a token. As already mentioned - check this url https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf

Going further - you can add ajax functionality to your form, but that's a topic of another question)

Comment: So, you're saying GET requests are not secure at all, because it's easy to be created by the bad guys?!

Comment: `At all`? Do you see these words in my answer?

Comment: Implicitly yes. You said "That's why we **need** to go deeper and use $_POST requests **only**".

Comment: Changed my answer a bit.

Comment: Thanks for being a nice chap.